# How to multiply a quaternion with a vector?

Tags: math, vector, quaternions, cesiumjs

I am using CesiumJs

I have a Quaternion (x,y,z,w)
I have a Vector (x,y,z)

I want to multiply that Quaternion by a Vector, basically at the moment I hjave a rotation, and I want to multiply that rotation with a Vector forward (0,0,1) in order to get a point in a direction, but CesiumJS do not have those function at the moment.

I know there is some way to multiply Vector with Quaternion, I was doing it in Unity, but I do not know exactly how

I found this formula  `v' = q * v * (q^-1)` but what exactly is `(q^-1)` ?

Comment: There are certainly different approaches for that, and I'm not deeply involved in cesium, but one simple approach should be to use `Matrix3.fromQuaternion` to create a 3x3 rotation matrix from the quaternion, and then use this matrix to rotate the vector as usual. If this helps (and nobody else posts an answer), I could try to extend it to an answer...

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? A quaternion? A vector of the same kind as the input vector? A different kind of vector? Something else? I think you are mixing "worlds" here. Did you consider adapting from one to the other? E.g. first turn the quaternion into a vector, then do the appropriate vector operation, in order to get a vector result. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "vectorize" the quaternion product i.e., writing it in terms of vector operations such as the dot product and the cross product. Doing that you will get a formula equivalent to the Euler-Rodrigues Formula [1]:

v' = v + 2 * r x (s * v + r x v) / m

where x represents the cross product, s and r are the scalar and vector parts of the quaternion, respectively, and m is the sum of the squares of the components of the quaternion.

[1] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Rodrigues_formula

Comment: what does the ' beside the v mean?

Comment: v' (read "v prime") is the rotated vector.

Answer (score 1):

Marco13's comment is correct.  in Cesium, Quaternions are typically converted to matrices prior to multiplication with vectors, and built-in functions exist for this purpose.

Here's a [Sandcastle demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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).

```
var position = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 1);  // x, y, z

// Could instead use:
// var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_Z.clone();

var quaternion = new Cesium.Quaternion(0.382683, 0, 0, 0.92388);  // x, y, z, w

// Could alternately use:  45 degrees (pi/4 radians) around X
//var quaternion = Cesium.Quaternion.fromAxisAngle(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_X, Math.PI / 4);

var matrix = Cesium.Matrix3.fromQuaternion(quaternion);

var scratch1 = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
var result = Cesium.Matrix3.multiplyByVector(matrix, position, scratch1);

console.log(result);

// Result will be: (0, -0.7071063400800001, 0.7071079759110002)
// The +Z vector was rotated 45 degrees towards -Y, in a counter-clockwise
// rotation as seen from the +X axis.
```